# how to add new page if table doesn't fit horizontally (fpdf)

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have this table to show in PDF and my paper orientation is set to landscape. My table is so big so that the rows don't fit in one page, and also the columns.

I can add new page for the unfitted rows by adding this code:

```
if($ya >= 167){
    $pdf->addPage();
    $ya = 20;
}
```

But, how can I add new page horizontally for unfitted columns?

I've tried the same code but exchange the `$ya` (Y-coordinate) with `$yi`(X-coordinate) on the table header, it works for the header but then the table content also moved to the new page from the very first column.

Comment: Once you add a page, you move to that page, and cannot go back to the previous page. You could either keep track of where your header was cut off, and return to it after you do all the rows for that page, or you can do it twice, with the 1st time used to track where new pages occur.

Comment: Do you need to stick with a standard paper size? Perhaps you can create the PDF with a custom paper size that fits your table width (see constructor function http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/fpdf.htm)

Comment: @dakdad unfortunately yes, I have to stick with a standard paper size